# Всплывающие окна в JS

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

как сделать всплывающее окно как в MyStat, компьютерная академия шаг, пример прикреплю снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю тебе проще всего будет использовать Bootstrap.
Тебе нужны Modals. Вот ссылка [Описание Modals в Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_modal.php)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В скриншоте не обязательно давать рекламу курсов по инвестициям, хватило бы обычного `Lorem ipsum...`

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать всплывающее окно как в MyStat

Предложу такой демонстрационный пример...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const os = document.querySelector('#shadow')
  os.style.display = 'block'
  const om = document.querySelector('#message')
  om.style.display = 'block'
  os.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    os.style.display = 'none'
    om.style.display = 'none'
  }, {once: true})
})
```

```css
#shadow {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  display: none;
}
#message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>

<div id='shadow'></div>
<div id='message'>
  <p>как сделать всплывающее окно как в MyStat, компьютерная академия шаг, пример прикреплю снизу</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но когда добавил его на сайт то он не отображается, а когда создал новый чтобы проверить то всё работает, почему это может быть

Comment: @Serhii, я ведь гадать не умею... Ты можешь сделать еще один вопрос, показать там свой код. Тогда можно будет посмотреть что там у тебя на работает...

Comment: можешь дать свои контакты, скину в лс